# Working Example of an Unit Test of a Ionic Page with lazy load

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner, ionic3

For some time I am trying to rewrite my 'broken' unit tests since lazy loading with IonicPageModule, without any luck.

Anyone who has some pointers or working examples is greatly appreciated.

Should no working example exist (which I doubt), I will help create one with the feedback gathered on this page.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [RomainFallet](https://github.com/RomainFallet/ionic-workflow-guide/issues/2) I've found (and recreated) a working ionic 3 Unit Test with lazy loading on his [github](https://github.com/RomainFallet/ionic-workflow-guide) (see 2.7), which I also share here for ease.

```
 /* Import Ionic & Angular core elements */
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

/* Import modules */
import { HomePageModule } from './home.module';

/* Import components */
import { AppComponent } from '../../app/app.component';

/* Import pages */
import { HomePage } from './home';

describe('HomePage', () => {
    let fixture;
    let component;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent),
                HomePageModule
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        })
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it ('should create a valid instance of HomePage', () => {
        expect(component instanceof HomePage).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Hope it also helps others finding their way.